# Put HTML form in Modal using angular

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a big form that fills in data using a web service. Here is what all I have working. On my main index.html:

```
<div id="showInfo" ">
            <div ng-include src="'people.html'" ng-controller="PeopleController as people"  > 
            </div>
        </div>
```

A controller that gets the information about people, people.js

```
    this.getPeople = function() {
        $scope.information = this;
        $http.get('myurl').success(function(data) {

            $scope.information.info =data;      
            console.log("Success");
        });
    }
}]);
```

In people.html, I have a table that uses ng-repeat to display some specific attributes that are always visible.

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Something 1</th>
                <th>Something 2</th>
                <th>Something 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="person in people.info">
                <td>{{person.somethintwo}}</a></td>
                <td>{{person.somethinfive}}</td>
                <td>{{person.somethinthree}}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-default"
                        ng-click="getPersonInformation(person)">More
                        Details</button></td>
                <div id="showModal">
                    <div ng-include src="'deviceForm.html'"
                        ng-controller="FormController as formcontrol"></div>
                </div>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Now what I want is that on clicking of more information, a modal window should pop up displaying my form with 20 entries. Then there should be a ng-submit function for sending updated data to server. I have the form as well and a controller to handle the form.

```
$scope.getPersonInformation(person) = function (person) {
    // I can retrieve information here of the person but want it to be displayed in a modal window on pop up

        };
```

I tried to follow a few links but unable to get the modal window working.

[http://plnkr.co/edit/DNHT1ekB12rlC9KSGzUU?p=preview]

[http://jsfiddle.net/alexsuch/RLQhh/]

[http://jsfiddle.net/hasan2002/huspb8to/]

If anyone can guide me would be great. Also, in those links it is mentioned to create a template within the modal directive. I have a big form, do I need to give the structure of the whole form as the template's value? In my people.html, I have incuded an ng-include for my form's template. Isnt that what is required.

Answer (score 0):

> Now what I want is that on clicking of more information, a modal
>   window should pop up displaying my form with 20 entries.

- Inject the modal service (`$uibModal`) to the main controller (`PeopleController`)
- To trigger the modal window, you just need to call the method `$uibModal.open` with some proper options, your code should look like:

```
$scope.getPersonInformation(person) = function (person) {
  var modalOptions = {
      templateUrl: 'deviceForm.html',
      controller: 'FormController',
      controllerAs: 'formcontrol',
      // here you pass your `person` object to the modal controller
      // [ along with any other piece of data if you want ;) ]
      resolve: {
        person: function () {
          return person;
        }
      }
  };
  $uibModal.open(modalOptions);
};
```

- Any object passed to the modal controller using `resolve` must be injected to the controller, for your case, `FormController` should be something like:

```
// here you inject `person` (that were passed using `resolve`) to `FormController`
yourAngularModule.controller('FormController', ['$scope', 'person', function($scope, person) {
  $scope.person = person;
}]);
```

- And finally, now you can display information of `person` object in the template, the template can be a remote file or an embedded script like this one:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="deviceForm.html">
<div class="modal-header"> bla bla </div>
<div class="modal-body"> 
  {{person}}
</div>
</script>
```

In case of embedded scripts, I like to place them at bottom of the page, and BTW you need only one embedded script, there is no need to place the template inside the `ng-repeat` construct, the template is instantiated every time by Angular and filled with the passed `person` object, that's why it's called a template!

**Note: remove this div `<div id="showModal">`**

> Then there should be a ng-submit function for sending updated data to
>   server. I have the form as well and a controller to handle the form

Straightforward, the form and the other submit stuff should be coded in `deviceForm.html` if I understood you well, I guess so :D, don't hesitate to discuss the solution with me!